# Text to speach automatically calls Speak Function in react-speech-kit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a speech-to-text command then the server will reply as text then convert it to speech using [react-speech-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-kit). Both function works fine, but what I wanted to do is call the `Speak()` function from `useSpeechSynthesis` automatically.

I've called the `speak` function on `onEnd` function from `useSpeechRecognition` like this

```
  const onEnd = () => {
    fetch(
      "http://api/Main?id=test&lang=kor&req=" +
        value,
      {}
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setResponse(result.res);
          speak(result.res);
          console.log(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    // You could do something here after speaking has finished
  };
```

But it doesn't speak for itself after the value has been passed.

Does anyone know how to make it automatic?

EDIT

I was wrong to call speak function like that, it should've be like this
`speak({text:result.res});` It is working now, TTS automatically calls, but it calls over and over again, not once, anyone knows how to fix it?